# Store console logging in Chrome in a persistent way

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, logging, console, persistent

In a school project I am running some javascript that are inputted through the console window and run from there. This script manipulates the web page and outputs the results to the console.

PROBLEM: Keep / save these results in a persistant manner that does not go away on browser close, script malfunctioning / page reload, or if possible, pc crash.

I thought of using frameworks such as Log4js or jStorage (jQuery Storage), but as this is not my website I'm manipulating, I can't add code or markup to the page.

Is there any way to do this?

NOTE: It is not critical that I log the results to console, I could send them off somewhere or do something else with them if that makes it more easy to log.

Thanks.

Comment: Chrome's console log can persist across page reloads, it's a built-in option.

Comment: Thanks. Might be useful if I cant work out the disk-logging function

Comment: A pity that OP never accepted an answer

Answer (score 9):

Here's a little function that stores logs into the [WebStorage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) (persists across browser sessions):

```
console.plog = function () {
    var key = Date.now();
    var value = JSON.stringify([].slice.call(arguments));
    localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    console.log.apply(console, arguments);
}
```

To restore the logs, you'd have to run the following expression:

```
(function restoreLogs() {
    var timestamps = Object.keys(localStorage).sort();
    timestamps.forEach(function (ts) {
        var logArgs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(ts));
        console.log.apply(console, logArgs);
    });
}());
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to automatically save everything in Chrome Console you have to run Chrome with these options:

```
--enable-logging --v=1
```

It'll save the full log of chrome inside its data directory (note that the file will be overwritten on each run). More details [here](http://chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging).

Alternative way: install the [Sawbuck](http://code.google.com/p/sawbuck/) utility to manage Chrome logs.

Comment: I cant seem to find the log file. Any idea where it is located? Im on a mac, I checked the package contents of the Chrome.app.

Comment: It should be on ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default, anyway check http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging

Comment: There is no folder Google under /Library/Application Support, however these two are there with some other subfolders.

I suspect something might be wrong with my Chrome arguments. I open it the following way:

/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --enable-logging --v=1

Is there any way to see if the app is running with the specified arguments?

Comment: I tried to set a custom user directory, which obviously worked as when I restarted Chrome it did not remember the previously opened tabs, as it has been doing. Still, no log file showed up in the newly specified folder after doing some console.logs and console.errors.
I even tried disabling hidden files, didnt work.
Weird!

Comment: Take a look at chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging, it should contain everything you need to set-up Chrome!

Comment: @ErikWendel, Uncertain if you found a solution for the side-trail issue. However, I am doing something similar with custom user directories - except on Windows, the path for a custom-directory is `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\<custom_directory>` and I think the equivalent on mac would be `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/<custom_directory>/chrome_debug.log` Hope this helps. @Adriano, thanks for the solution/link.

Comment: Having to check a separate file is an annoying extra step. You can get the results in the terminal as well: ["With `--enable-logging=stderr` the output will be printed to standard error (not available on Windows)"](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging)

Answer (score 1):

Use `console.error(arg);` - it will send the console message into the browser's `stderr` (I'm pretty sure it will do so in the release builds, too.)

Start your browser from the command line and redirect your `stderr` into some file (something along the lines of `chrome 2>errlog`).

Comment: You mean the argument following --args should be 2>errlog, meaning that logs of level 2 (errors) are logged to file errlog?

Any idea where this file would be saved? Im on a mac.

Comment: `2>errlog` means "redirect stderr (which has a handle of 2) into a file called 'errlog'". You can provide any file name (including the full path.)

Comment: I specified a full path, and after restarting Chrome the file was created, which is a good sign. Still, after I've executed some console.error(args) which shows the argument back to me in red text, its not added to the text file. The only line in the text file is the following: 
[0418/164110:INFO:breakpad_mac.mm(148)] Breakpad disabled

This is my AppleScript-script to open Chrome with the arguments:
do shell script "/Applications/Google\\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\\ Chrome --enable-logging --v=1 2>/Users/*myusername*/Documents/errlog.txt"